# How to manage state of Search page after navigating back from details page in Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-routing

In my application search page select search criteria then i have navigate to second page (component) after back to search screen criteria reset and reload component so please give me solution how to prevent reload or manage criteria when navigate the page.
Thanks.

Comment: use [local storage](https://alligator.io/js/introduction-localstorage-sessionstorage/) to persist state

Comment: you can use a service to store that search criteria

Answer (score 1):

1. You can push the search criteria to the url and then when you want
   to navigate back your component can subscribe to route change and
   react to the current url. (This I think is the best aproach)
2. Another aproach can be to use a singleton service which I don't recomand cause it will introduce state in your application which needs to be cleaned at some point.